# regex in python, can this be improved upon?

Tags: python, regex

I have this piece of code that finds words that begin with @ or #,

```
p = re.findall(r'@\w+|#\w+', str)
```

Now what irks me about this is repeating \w+. I am sure there is a way to do something like

```
p = re.findall(r'(@|#)\w+', str)
```

That will produce the same result but it doesn't, it instead returns only `#` and `@`. How can that regex be changed so that I am not repeating the `\w+`? This code comes close,

```
p = re.findall(r'((@|#)\w+)', str)
```

But it returns `[('@many', '@'), ('@this', '@'), ('#tweet', '#')]` (notice the extra '@', '@', and '#'.

Also, if I'm repeating this `re.findall` code 500,000 times, can this be compiled and to a pattern and then be faster?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### The solution

You have two options:

- Use non-capturing group: `(?:@|#)\w+`
- Or even better, a character class: `[@#]\w+`

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Character Class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and [Groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

---

#### Understanding `findall`

The problem you were having is due to how `findall` return matches depending on how many capturing groups are present.

Let's take a closer look at this pattern (annotated to show the groups):

```
((@|#)\w+)
|\___/   |
|group 2 |     # Read about groups to understand
\________/     # how they're defined and numbered/named
 group 1
```

Capturing groups allow us to save the matches in the subpatterns within the overall patterns.

```
p = re.compile(r'((@|#)\w+)')
m = p.match('@tweet')
print m.group(1)
# @tweet
print m.group(2)
# @
```

Now let's take a look at the Python documentation for the `re` module:

> [`findall`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html): Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group.

This explains why you're getting the following:

```
str = 'lala @tweet boo #this &that @foo#bar'

print(re.findall(r'((@|#)\w+)', str))
# [('@tweet', '@'), ('#this', '#'), ('@foo', '@'), ('#bar', '#')]
```

As specified, since the pattern has more than one group, `findall` returns a list of tuples, one for each match. Each tuple gives you what were captured by the groups for the given match.

The documentation also explains why you're getting the following:

```
print(re.findall(r'(@|#)\w+', str))
# ['@', '#', '@', '#']
```

Now the pattern only has one group, and `findall` returns a list of matches for that group.

In contrast, the patterns given above as solutions doesn't have any capturing groups, which is why they work according to your expectation:

```
print(re.findall(r'(?:@|#)\w+', str))
# ['@tweet', '#this', '@foo', '#bar']

print(re.findall(r'[@#]\w+', str))
# ['@tweet', '#this', '@foo', '#bar']
```

#### References

- [docs.python.org - Regular Expression HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/regex.html)

  - [Compiling Regular Expressions](http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/regex.html#compiling-regular-expressions)
  - [Grouping](http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/regex.html#grouping) | [Non-capturing and Named Groups](http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups)
- [docs.python.org - `re` module](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)

#### Attachments

- [Snippet with output on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/HVUGa)

Comment: Thanks! Is this something that can be compiled and then reused in a pattern?

Comment: @tipu - 'anything' can be compiled/reused,  don't forget to accept the answer

Comment: @tipu: I've updated the answer with more Python-specific information.